# What is the best practice to hande media types and CSS

Tags: html, css

Further down is the whole CSS file. This css file can detect when the width of the browser is

1. max 480px
2. between 481 and 1024
3. greater then 1024

For example here I detect when browser is max 480px

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    body
    {
       background : #68838B url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

A lot of my css styles in this document is valid also when the width of the brwser
is max 480, between 481 and 1024 or greater then 1024.

So my question is what way is the best way to do ?
The way that I have done in this css file
is put everything that is common without any kind media queries as you can see.
For example if I want my background to be red when the browser width is max 480px I use this media rule

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    body
    {
       background : red url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

The whole CSS file
    body
    {
        width:80%;
        font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:small;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        margin:0.2em auto;
    }

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
   screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    body
    {
       background : #68838B url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and
   (max-width: 1024px)
{
    body
    {
        background : #B0E0E6 url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px)
{
    body
    { 
       background : #87a5be url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}

.roundcorder
{
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}

#home nav li.home a:link, 
#home nav li.home a:visited,
#aircraft nav li.aircraft a:link, 
#aircraft nav li.aircraft a:visited,
#bookning nav li.bookning a:link, 
#bookning nav li.bookning a:visited,
#contact nav li.contact a:link, 
#contact nav li.contact a:visited,
#employee nav li.employee a:link, 
#employee nav li.employee a:visited
{
    background-color: #fff;
}  

p#browser
{
   margin:0;
   padding:0; 
}   


header img
{
   float:left;
}

header #headerInfo
{
   font-size:100%;
   float:right; 
   padding-top:0.4em;
   padding-right:0.8em;
   font-style:italic;
}

header div:after, 
nav:after
{
   content :".";
   display:block;
   height:0;
   clear:both;
   visibility:hidden;
}

nav
{
   margin-top:1em;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#fff; 
}

nav ul
{
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

nav li
{
   float: left;
   min-width : 5em;
   text-align : center;   
   margin-right:0.5em; 
}

nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited
{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   color: rgb(0,0,0);
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 0.75em;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}   

nav li a:hover 
{
   background-color:gray;  
}

section 
{
   font-size:115%;
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000;
   padding: 0.5em;
}

section h1
{
   text-align:center;
   font-size:200%;
}

footer
{
   padding: 0.1em;
   background:#e3e3e3;
   font-size:90%;
   text-align:center;
   border-top:1px solid #000;
}

footer address
{
   margin-bottom:0.5em;
}

@media print
{
   body
   { 
      width:750pt;
      background-color:#fff;
      font-family: "times new roman", times, serif;
      font-size:14pt;
   }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach. Is there any reason you think something might be wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is asking for opinions, which is not the right kind of question for this site. There will probably not be a singular "correct" answer. Just a lot of subjective thoughts.

Comment: Anyway, my subjective though is that you should take the background-image of the body out of the media queries and put it in one place instead of repeating it in three.

Comment: I have done this for the background just to see that each media query will be true when I change the width of the browser.